# What is the proper way to deal with rounding error?

Tags: c++, numeric-precision

I am currently working on a Physics Engine in C++.  The Physics Engine is for a sandbox video game. I want to build a powerful physics engine, so therefore, it needs to be very precise.

I have written the following function:

```
Vector3D* rotationX(double theta);
```

This function will rotate a vector around the x-axis at theta degrees.  My test attempts to rotate the vector <0,1,0> about the x-axis, which should be the vector <0,0,1>.  The output is the following vector, which is very close to what it should be: <0,0.000796327,1>.

I am aware of the floor function, but I think this isn't precise enough since my 3-d vector class should be able to handle real numbers; that is, not just integers.

Comment: You are not handling real numbers. You are not even handling rational numbers. You are handling floating point numbers. If you need to handle rational numbers, you'll need a library for handling arbitrary precision "decimal" numbers.

Comment: The result you have is _not_ very close at all. That's not due to rounding error, there is some serious bug in your code.

Comment: Its best to publish the code.

Comment: Have you quantified how precise it needs to be?

Comment: @TKK problems fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have basically the following options:

1.) Do nothing. Maybe the result is precise enough for your use case. Note when using floating point operations, it is quite normal you have to deal with some rounding errors. I would recommend to have a look at [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

2.) If your use case involves comparing two vectors for equality, make sure you compare against some "epsilon", where epsilon is about 10^(-3).

3.) Find out why the result is **that much** imprecise. A rotation involving standard trigonometric functions which uses 64 bit double precision should usually bring results up to a preciseness better than 10^(-10) to my experience.

In between, it became clear (see comments) that in this case the root cause was using 3.14 as an approximation for [Pi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi). It is usually a good idea to use predefined constants for such standard values whenever they are available in the used environment. In C++, for example, one can use the constant `M_PI` from `<math.h>` (see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727881/how-to-use-the-pi-constant-in-c)).

Comment: I am using trigonometric functions for rotation, and in particular the following:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_three_dimensions

Comment: Also, the reason why it's not precise is because the value 0.000796327 should be 0.

Comment: I am using a double data type.

Comment: Let me make an educated guess: You are using a five or six digit approximation for pi somewhere.

Comment: @DocBrown With double precision, I'd expect much smaller errors, say 10^(-15).

Comment: I actually set pi to 3.14, and did a 90 degree rotation, so pi/2 was sent as input.  That's why the result vector should have been <0,0,1>.

Comment: Pi is much more precise now, so the new vector result is <0,-1.03e-13,1>.  This is much more precise.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @GaryDrocella: so what did you expect? You cut pi to 2 digits, which is pretty imprecise - why should the result then be more precise then 2 or 3 digits?

Comment: Yes, M_PI made it much more precise. Rotated vector is now <0,6.12e-17,1>.  Thanks again!  This is much better because it means that I can use an epsilon of 1e-9.

Comment: The almost but not quite zero value was sin (3.14) / 2

Comment: Seems like it's time for @GaryDrocella to do some more reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures